# linked-In callback function not working

Tags: function, callback, linkedin-api

I am using below code to share content to linkedIn, but callback on success is not working.I am using data-onsuccess attribute.

Comment: You didn't include the code

Comment: please refer: https://forums.envato.com/t/linkedin-share-callback/75571